# $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ implies there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\int_{(-\infty, a]} f = \int_{[a, \infty)} f$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, real-numbers

In studying for a qualifying exam, I found a problem asking me to prove:

> If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ has $\int_\mathbb{R} f \neq 0$, then there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\int_{(-\infty, a]} f = \int_{[a, \infty)} f$

I'm sure the answer probably has something to do with the fact that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ requires $|f|$ to be "sufficiently small" as it gets far away from $0$, but I'm really stumped on where to begin with either finding the a relative to f, or showing (i.e., by contradiction) that such an a must exist even without "finding" it.

Comment: Can you prove that $x\rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^x f$ is continuous?

Comment: try showing that $a\mapsto \int_a^\infty f$ is continuous. Then check what happens for $a\rightarrow \pm \infty$

Comment: Well, I feel silly for having forgotten the basics of absolute continuity. Hopefully I'll remember that on the real test now.